# Try to use hibernate 3.4 in JBoss 5.1 but gets javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider

Tags: hibernate, spring, jboss, spring-roo, hibernate-validator

I've come across some problems using Hibernate 3.4 on JBoss 5.1.
Hibernate 3.4 is a JPA 1.0 implementation so it should be fine to be used in JBoss 5.1. The thing is JBoss has its own version of Hibernate, which is located at /common/lib whereas I don't want to use the version provided by JBoss. What I did was that I removed the hibernate-annotations.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations.jar, hibernate-core.jar, hibernate-entitymanager.jar, hibernate-jmx.jar and hibernate-validator.jar from that folder and put my Hibernate 3.4 jars into server/default/lib directory. I also compiled hibernate-validator.jar 3.1.0 into my war file because it seems otherwise JBoss cannot recognize where the validator is. After I have done all the above, I packaged my war file and deployed it to the deploy folder.

The server started with no issue. But when I tried to access my web application it throws an error:

> *2010-10-27 10:55:13,416 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost]]
>   (http-172.16.10.211-80-1) Exception
>   Processing
>   ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Exception,
>   location=/app/uncaughtException]
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   Servlet.init() for servlet roodummy
>   threw exception at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:777)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:607)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:446)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:416)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0':
>   Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   javax.validation.ValidationException:
>   Unable to find a default provider at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
>   ... 16 more Caused by:
>   javax.validation.ValidationException:
>   Unable to find a default provider at
>   javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
>   at
>   org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:161)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
>   ... 32 more*

It looks like it still cannot find the validator. But it is already in the war file.  I have tested my web app in a jetty server and it worked fine. What have I done wrong in the JBoss configuration?

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is JBoss has its own version of Hibernate, which is located at /common/lib whereas I don't want to use the version provided by JBoss.

I think that the recommended approach would be to bundle the libs you want to use in your application and to configure JBoss to load jars from your application first, using a jboss-web.xml with the following content (see [ClassLoadingConfiguration](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration)):

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
    <loader-repository>
        unique.packege.name:archive=your_project.war
        <loader-repository-config>
            java2ParentDelegation=false
        </loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

I've not tested this myself when using Bean Validation but a user reported in [this thread](http://community.jboss.org/thread/156832) (and also [this one](http://community.jboss.org/thread/153894)) he still had to replace the bundled validator from `common/lib`. This sounds strange and I can't confirm it's required. Try without first.

Comment: There is only one validator which is in the war file. I have already removed the validator from the common/lib. I think the classloader should try to get it from war file if it could not find it elsewhere.

Comment: @newguy: I don't think classes from common/lib can load something from your webapp. However, the inverse would work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer.
I had this problem when I was using hibernate-validator 3.0.1 I changed it to 4.2.0.Final and it works fine.

also, make sure you have validator-api jar installed